# Weird characters in XML response

Tags: python, xml, sockets, http, post

I try to communicate with our supplier with XML over HTTP.

So far, my request is something like:

```
POST /some-service HTTP/1.1
Host: me
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 470

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<PNARequest>
    <Version>2.0</Version>
    <TransactionHeader>
        <SenderID>My Company</SenderID>
        <ReceiverID>My Supplier</ReceiverID>
        <CountryCode>FR</CountryCode>
        <LoginID>My Login</LoginID>
        <Password>My Password</Password>
        <TransactionID>some hexa numbers</TransactionID>
    </TransactionHeader>
    <PNAInformation Quantity="1" SKU="more numbers here"/>
    <ShowDetail>2</ShowDetail>
</PNARequest>
```

(The content-length may differ, because I changed the body after I've pasted it.)

I send it on the port 443 of my supplier, with no encryption (testing purposes).
Before, I had a correct response, with a nice XML structure. Now, all I have as a response is this:

```
'\x15\x03\x00\x00\x02\x02\n'
```

I have this displayed by Python using: `print repr(response)`

And this is the full response, not just the body. No headers, nothing like that.

On the supplier side, they don't even see my request in their logs. So, any clue of what is going on ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

**Update**

Here's my Python code for sending this request (note that this is just a script to test the communication process, and see what is really exchanged):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import socket

def condense(body):
    body = re.sub(' +<','<', body)
    return body.replace('\n', '')

def post(host, port, api, body, content_type="text/xml; charset=utf-8", 
         me="my.ip"):
    body = condense(body)
    lines = [
        "POST {} HTTP/1.1".format(api),
        "Host: {}".format(me),
        "Content-Type: {}".format(content_type),
        "Content-Length: {}".format(len(body)),
        "",
        "{}".format(body),
        "",
        "",
    ]
    msg = "\r\n".join(lines)

    s = socket.create_connection((host, port))
    s.send(msg)
    print "REQUEST ##############################################"
    print msg

    res = ""
    data = True
    while data:
        data = s.recv(8192)
        res += data

    s.close()
    print "RESPONSE #############################################"
    print res
    print 


def unpack_post(d, **kwargs):
    post(d["host"], d["port"], d["api"], d["body"], **kwargs)

my_supplier = {
    "host": "my.supplier.com",
    "port": 443,
    "api": "/some-api",
    "body": """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<PNARequest>
    <Version>2.0</Version>
    <TransactionHeader>
        <SenderID>Your Company</SenderID>
        <ReceiverID>My Supplier</ReceiverID>
        <CountryCode>FR</CountryCode>
        <LoginID>My Login</LoginID>
        <Password>My Password</Password>
        <TransactionID>Some Hexa Numbers</TransactionID>
    </TransactionHeader>
    <PNAInformation Quantity="1" SKU="More Numbers Here"/>
    <ShowDetail>2</ShowDetail>
</PNARequest>""",
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unpack_post(my_supplier)
```

I know this is a little ugly, but I did that just for testing purposes so...
And I wrote this code because I like to test on multiple servers, like https://www.200please.com/, ...

Comment: Please elaborate on how you send your request.  Post the code, so we can try to find bugs in that part.  If the server does not log your request, maybe it does not see it.  Maybe a firewall blocks it.  Maybe, maybe, maybe; there's just too many options here.  We can try to find errors in what we see but it is very hard to _guess_ errors in things we do not see, so provide _everything_ you have.

Comment: I was poting here in case someone had the same issue. Because, indeed, it depends on so much things on the server side... Besides, I just had an email today from my supplier that could explain the problem (but they don't explain all what they are doing...) But for the sake of the community, I will post my code, and hopefully someone will think that helpfull. (sry for my bad English)

Comment: Got my ⁺¹ for your effort :)

Comment: Thanks ! Perhaps I should make my own answer now, because as I was saying, it's probably an issue on the server side. What do you think ?

Comment: SO allows exactly that, and you should then accept your own answer.  This way this question isn't listed among the "open" unanswered questions anymore.  So, yes, go ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I was saying in one of my comments, this is probably due to a server side issue.

I know this is not a perfect answer, but since my supplier don't share their logs with me, I can just guess things...

I'll edit this answer later, if I find new things to share, but I don't since this is not a programming issue anymore (again, I guess here), that is not the place for that.

Comment: "You can accept you own answer tomorrow." Dammit, I must not forget this !